# Multiple "overlays" using same addresses in IDA

Tags: ida

I am debugging an old Sony PlayStation 1 MIPS binary that swaps a bunch of submodules using same base address for loading. I am trying to find a workflow that would allow me to have all the submodules loaded at the same time.

From my understanding it's impossible to create overlapping segments in IDA, so I tried loading the binary at a higher address(outside of the 2MB of RAM IDA expects), but IDA doesn't like this - code blocks are not automatically detected and when forced - offsets are all wrong(not a big surprise). So do I have any options here? Looks like other way around is to try to sync data between multiple projects, but based on other answers - that's far from perfect too.